# How to make a link url go through another page when clicked HTML

Tags: html

I'm sorry I do not know how to word that title better. I have tried searching google but my terminology isn't helping my results.

Let me explain the context. When you're on a news website or blog and you're on their homepage like: www.homepage.co.uk/ and then you click an article it will go somewhere like this: www.homepage.co.uk/2017/article/ how do they make the 2017 appear? because if you remove the /article/ from the url it takes you to an archive of all the links in that year? I don't understand, is there a process to this?

When I click a link in my website it goes to: www.website.co.uk/link
I want to be able to have that 2017/link/ in the url so they can find the archive of that year just like on their websites?
How do I do this?

I am sorry if I am not explaining this very well.

I understand changing my filenames to : "2017/article.html" might work but I do not believe that is the correct way of doing it?

Thanks a lot for your time and suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking about a couple of things: one is the taxonomy of the site.  Taxonomy, if you don't know, is the "shape" of or how your site is organized.  News sites, for instance, are usually organized by date and perhaps topic (Health and Leisure, Politics, Entertainment, etc.). The other aspect of your question is regarding what you might call RESful "hacking" of URLs.  One of the tenents of REST is that URLS (uri, to be accurate) are supposed to be hackable.  A news site might have /2017/10/10 to display all articles for Oct 10.  Maybe you remove the last "10", and get all the articles for October so far.  If you are not using a site platform that does this for you, you will have to maintain that taxonomy yourself, and manually write all the links.  Systems such as Drupal and Joomla, among others, will translate your taxonomy into automatically-maintained links.  In editing a page on one of these platforms, you typically only refer to the system's internal name of the page (could be a shortened version of the article's title in the above example), and the underlying engine takes care of reconstructing the URL for you (in case the page moves, or its tags/taxonomy changes).

This is a big topic, and I encourage you to do some further reading:

http://searchcontentmanagement.techtarget.com/feature/Building-a-website-taxonomy-in-eight-steps

https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/organizing-content-with-taxonomies/organizing-content-with-taxonomies

Comment: Thank you so much for your input! Do you think I should go into my html and add change to 2017/article myself then create a 2017.html page and list links that way... this would be the temporary shortcut version of what you just suggested. I am not using joomla or any other platform I am doing it from scratch. Kind regards!

Comment: I believe [this resource](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp) might help you. You could simply create yourself the folders to get the path you need, e.g. In your site's root, create a folder named "2017" then inside that a folder named  "articles" and then inside that place your file "my-article.html." The url for this file would be "yoursite.com/2017/articles/my-article.html"